# Using the return value of a statement

Tags: c, return, statements

I want to know if it is possible to use the return value of a statement in C.

For example: If I start with `a=0;` then I know that the expression `a++` will return 0 while `a+=1` will return 1. But talking about statements, is there any semantic difference between `a++;` and `a+=1;`?

At first, they both look like they have similar behavior and, so, the only difference could be the existence of a way of using the return values of statements. Is it possible?

Comment: GCC has an extension called [Statement Expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) you could look into, but that's not standard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Statements don't have return values. Expressions have values (unless of type `void`). Some expressions also have side effects.

`a++` has a value equal to the original value of `a` and `a+=1` has a value of one greater than the original value of `a`.

Assigning a new value to `a` is a side effect. Both expressions have the same side effect.

There's nothing more complicated about any of this. Do note though, that depending on a side effect within the same statement (not just the same subexpression) produces undefined behavior, unless there is a sequence point. Multiple side effects within the same statement, and side effect dependencies, are a more advanced topic so it is better to keep assignment statements simple.

Comment: Sorry for being so confusing. I will give another example: main(){ int a=0; a++; ...rest of the code } main(){ int a=0; a+=1; ...rest of the code } Is it possible to put anything in the rest of the code so that this programs hae different behavior?

Comment: @user3094142 No. The expressions have exactly the same side effect.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: So it does. C’s atomic features are new to me too.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I would take "See the discussions of additive operators and compound assignment for information on constraints, types, side effects" in the prefix spec to mean the behavior is uniform, although they should be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

You want to compare `++a` and `(a+=1)` which will both return 1

`a++` means return the old value and then change `a`

`++a` means add one to `a`, and return the new value

`(a+=1)` means add one to a and return the new value (but technically it can be slower)

On its own line, `++a`, `a++` and `a+=1` are all the same thing

if you call: `foo(a++)` and `foo(a+=1)` foo will be passed the different values.

Technically `++a` can be faster than `a+=1`, but any level of optimization should result in the same thing

Comment: No. Sorry for being so confusing. I will give another example:
main(){
int a=0;
a++;
...rest of the code
}
main(){
int a=0;
a+=1;
...rest of the code
}

Is it possible to put anything in the rest of the code so that this programs hae different behavior?

Comment: why should `++a` be faster than `a+=1`? If you are thinking about some  processors having an `inc` instruction, "faster" than a `add 1` where at least an extra immediate value must be fetched from the mem (the 1... though cpus, e.g. 680x0, may have some other kind of "optimization" depending on the val to be added, not on how you express it in C), ... but not all cpus have that instruction.

Comment: @ShinTakezou reduced the statement to "can be", and yes that is what I meant.  But as mentioned any level of optimization will use the same best expression for both